# Chi-square Goodness of Fit for a Test of Normality in r

Tags: r, normal-distribution, chi-squared

I want to test for normality of a set of data using `Chi-Square Goodness of Fit Test` in `R` just the way I tested for Shapiro- wilk test. I have my sample sizes to be `10, 20,50 and 100` while my `replicate is 1000`

```
## Shapiro- wilk test [sw]

x <- rnorm(x, 0, 1)
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
  table(replicate(1000,shapiro.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",] < 0.05)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out

#     FALSE TRUE
# 10    947   53
# 20    945   55
# 50    943   57
# 100   943   57
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Googling "R chi-square test normality" gets to https://rdrr.io/cran/DescTools/man/PearsonTest.html which looks like it should be easy to adapt/plug into your framework ...

Comment: Quick google search solve this problem: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r, https://www.statology.org/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r/, https://rpubs.com/pg2000in/ChiSquareGoodnessFit

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the chi test get non negative values.
Try replacing the table calculation with this code:

```
table(replicate(1000,chisq.test(x=abs(rnorm(x)),p=c(rep(1/x,x))))["p.value",] < 0.05)
```

Comment: `Error in rep(1/x, x) : invalid 'times' argument`

Comment: I tried this `table(replicate(1000, chisq.test(x = abs(rnorm(x)), p = c(rep(1/x,length(x)))))["p.value",] < 0.05)` it brings `Error in chisq.test(x = abs(rnorm(x)), p = c(rep(1/x, length(x)))) : 
  'x' and 'p' must have the same number of elements`

Comment: length(x) will always be 1 inside the sapply, because x takes this vector: c(10, 20, 50, 100). When I get home I re test it using your exact code. Then I update my comment if you have no solution by the time.

Comment: Just one question, for this chi test, do you have the same probability within each sample or do you have a change ?